# WP-PageNavi is showing the first page only

Tags: php, pagination, plugin-wp-pagenavi

I am using WP-PageNavi plugin, which I incorporated into my custom tpl page. There is woocommerce shortcode which holds all the products that I want to display, but I only ever see the same ones and only one page results. I do not see what am I doing wrong. The code is:

```
  <?php 
    /* Template Name: shine*/ 
    ?>
    <?php get_header(); ?>

    <div class="wrapper clearfix">


            <?php $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'page',
                    'orderby' => 'title',
                    'order' => 'ASC',
                    'posts_per_page' => 5,
                    'paged' => get_query_var('paged'),

                ); ?>
          <?php query_posts($args); ?>

          <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
              <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

              <?php endwhile; ?>
          <?php endif; ?>





            <h2>SHINE kolekcija</h2>    


    <?php

 echo do_shortcode( '[product_attribute attribute="kolekcije" filter="shine"]' );
  ?>

 <div class="naviButs">
            <?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>
        </div>



            </div>




    <?php  get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: You want to show pagination of what? Products pagination? or anything else's?

Comment: Yes, products pagination. I managed to show pagination, but it always shows the same result. The code above is what I have now.  For example - I click on page 2 or 3 and I still see the results  from page 1. Whatever pagination page I want to see, it always shows the same results. (and that is products from page one)

Answer (score 1):

In case of `wp_query`, you can't use shortcode this way

```
<?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>
```

You need to use variable (in which you are storing wp_query) in array inside shortcode. Use shortcode like this instead. Replace above shortcode with below one.

```
<?php wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $query_slider ) ); ?>
```

**UPDATE**

This is a way in which I am using `wp_query` to show products list without shortcode that you used to display products.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: shine
*/
get_header(); ?>
<?php 
$paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array('post_type' => 'product',
'orderby' => 'title',
'order' => 'ASC',
'posts_per_page' => 5, 
'paged' => $paged);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
?>
 <li style="list-style:none;">
    <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title();?></a>&nbsp;(<?php echo get_the_date('d.m.Y');?>)</h3>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
    <?php 
/*****     Thumbnail     ******/
the_post_thumbnail(
    array(120, 90), 
    array(

        'class' => 'enter-class-here',   //Specify class for product's image if any
        'alt' => 'Preview unavailable', //Specify alternate text for products, in case if there is no products image
        'title' => 'Enter-title-here'  //Specify title if any
    )
);
/*******     Thumbnail Ends   ********/
?>      </a>   
</li><hr />
<?php 
endwhile; ?>

<?php wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $loop ) ); ?>
<?php get_footer();?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am not trying to show custom post slide pagination (which is why I said the woocommerce shortcode is where I am  pulling my products from). I am trying to paginate the products that I get from that woocommerce shortcode. I will edit the code to show only relevant lines.

Comment: @Nancy Check the updated answer

Comment: this way the pagination is working, BUT now it shows all products. The shortcode I used was to show only products for which I set  custom attribute named "shine". Would you know how to manage that?

Comment: @Nancy Sorry, No Idea right now! Either search on google to find way to filter products list or wait for better answer by someone else :)

Comment: I appreciate you trying to help, anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Using `query_posts` will always kill any hope of any pagination to be successfully done. You should use the `pre_get_posts` filter to adjust the main query if you care about pagination.

It will be actually hard to achieve if you need whatever you do in a context of a page template and you should better use your own URL structure by adding appropriate rewrite rules.